# Getting started with robotics

Tags: programming-languages

I'm getting started with robotics, as a side project while I'm still studying, I'm taking mechatronics at the moment, with prior knowledge of coding i learned a little bit of python and i have it easy while learning new languages, so i wanted to know what language should I start with on robotics, i plan on using arduino boards, i hear they use C and C++ i also researched that C is faster and more efficient than C++ tho it's harder to right code in since I don't know much about either Wich one should I be be learning to start with robotics?

Comment: You will need a lot of robotics experience, before the execution speed difference due to the compiler starts to matter, so just start with Python if you already know Python, or C++ if it is easier for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start learning robotic, the first thing you need to learn is the robotic and control it self.

About programming language, you actually can use C, C++ and Python (three most common language in robotic).

C and C++ will be used together, so learn both. But if you want to reduce the workload on programming and more focus on hardware and robotic control etc., you can use python like I did.

**Upside of C & C++** :

You can achieve real time control

**Downside** :

Take a lot more effort in programming side, i.e. you need to create your own function for matrix operation

**Upside of Python** :

Reducing work load on programming side

Easier if u wanna implement image processing in robotic

**Downside** :

Slower process, unlikely to achieve real time control performance

Comment: So tho i know more about robotics and electronics in general, about the programing you think I should start learning C and C++, or just stick with python, my goal would be to eventually study towards machine learning but I would like to get more knowledge around robotics (software) before trying to learn AI from scratch

Comment: Since u mention machine learning, then it is stick to python. Learning some basic on C & C++ would help when programming Arduino.